# $K_v(a^{1/m}) /K_v$ is unramified if only if $v(a)≡0 \pmod m$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-fields

> Let $K$ be a number field and $v$ be it's one of $K$'s non-archimedian valuation.
> Then, I would like to prove $K_v(a^{1/m})  /K_v$ is  unramified if
> only if $v(a)≡0 \pmod m$.

This is from Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', p213.
I know unramified extension of local field is in bijection with extensions of the residue field. Thus, the unramified extension is generated by roots of unity of order prime to the character of residue field of local field.

But I don't have tactics to judge given extension is unramified or not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The corresponding question on [math.se]: [$K_v(a^{1/m}) /K_v$ is unramified if only if $v(a)\equiv0 \pmod m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4249543)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I'm afraid the question was cross-posted about 12 hours before you posted your comment (and I posted my answer about 7 hours before your comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $v(a)\not\equiv 0\pmod m$, ramification is easy: just consider the valuation of the element $a^{1/m}$.

The converse is a little subtler than you make it seem, and depending on how exactly you phrase it, it need not be true: for instance, if $m=p$ coincides with the residue characteristic of $v$, $a=1$ and we interpret $a^{1/m}$ as a primitive $p$-th root of unity, the extension *will* be ramified.

Silverman includes a number of assumptions which exclude this case: he takes $v\not\in S$, and a couple paragraphs above it is stated that we assume this imples $v(m)=0$. Assuming this is the case and that $v(a)\equiv 0\pmod m$, note that, by multiplying $a$ by some $m$-th power, we may assume $v(a)=0$. Now, the polynomial $X^m-a$ has discriminant $\pm m^ma^{m-1}$, which under all these assumptions has valuation zero. This implies the discriminant of the extension $K_v(\sqrt[m]{a})/K_v$ is a $v$-adic unit, which implies the extension is unramified.

Comment: May I ask two questions ? ①Sorry to bother, but could you tell me the first paragraph? From $v(a^{1/m})＝ v(a)/m$ is not zero mod $m$, why can I say ramification? ② Let $L/K$ be extension of local field $K$, then $L/K$ is unramified is equivalent to discriminant of $L/K$ is $v-$adic unit ?

Comment: 1. If $v(a)\neq 0\pmod m$, then $v(a^{1/m})$ is not an integer. Existence of such elements is more or less the definition of ramification. 2. Yes

Comment: I'm confused. $v$ is valuation on $K$, and $a^{1/m}$ is not necessarily in $K$, what do you mean by $v(a^{1/m})$? Are you thinking some kind of extension of valuation ?

Comment: @Nekojiru A valuation on a local field uniquely extends to all its algebraic extensions. It is not uncommon to denote it by the same symbol.

Comment: Could you tell me where did we used $v$ is not belong to $S$ ?

Comment: Do we need to know also that $a^{1/m}$ is a monogenerator for the ring of integers in $K_v(a^{1/m})$ over the ring of integers in $K_v$? The discriminant of the polynomial $X^m - a$ is the discriminant of the basis $1, a^{1/m}, a^{2/m},...$, but this might not be the discriminant of the $L / K$, no?

Comment: @stillconfused I'm assuming you are referring to the last part. The discriminant of the extension divides the discriminant of any of the elements of $O_L$ which generate $L/K$. Since the discriminant of $a^{1/m}$ is a unit, so must be the discriminant of the extension.